# Java NIO client

Tags: java, client, selector, nio

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.*;

public class EchoServer {
    private InetAddress addr;
    private int port;
    private Selector selector;
    private Map<SocketChannel,List<byte[]>> dataMap;

    public EchoServer(InetAddress addr, int port) throws IOException {
        this.addr = addr;
        this.port = port;
        dataMap = new HashMap<SocketChannel,List<byte[]>>();
        startServer();
    }

    private void startServer() throws IOException {
        // create selector and channel
        this.selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // bind to port
        InetSocketAddress listenAddr = new InetSocketAddress(this.addr, this.port);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(listenAddr);
        serverChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        log("Echo server ready. Ctrl-C to stop.");

        // processing
        while (true) {
            // wait for events
            this.selector.select();

            // wakeup to work on selected keys
            Iterator keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();

                // this is necessary to prevent the same key from coming up 
                // again the next time around.
                keys.remove();

                if (! key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                }
                else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    this.read(key);
                }
                else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    this.write(key);
                }
                else if (key.isConnectable()) {
                    this.doConnect(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void doConnect(SelectionKey key) {
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            if (channel.finishConnect()) {
                    /* success */
                    System.out.println("Connected");
            } else {
                    /* failure */
                    System.out.println("failure");
            }
    }
    public void connect(String hostname, int port) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel clientChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        clientChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        clientChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname,port));
        clientChannel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
        clientChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("$Hello "+UserInfo[0]+"|").getBytes("US-ASCII")));
    }
    private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);

        // write welcome message
        channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("Welcome, this is the echo server\r\n".getBytes("US-ASCII")));

        Socket socket = channel.socket();
        SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
        log("Connected to: " + remoteAddr);        
        dataMap.put(channel, new ArrayList<byte[]>()); // register channel with selector for further IO
        channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
    private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
        int numRead = -1;
        try {
            numRead = channel.read(buffer);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (numRead == -1) {
            this.dataMap.remove(channel);
            Socket socket = channel.socket();
            SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
            log("Connection closed by client: " + remoteAddr);
            channel.close();
            key.cancel();
            return;
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[numRead];
        System.arraycopy(buffer.array(), 0, data, 0, numRead);
        log("Got: " + new String(data, "US-ASCII"));        
        doEcho(key, data); // write back to client
    }
    private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        List<byte[]> pendingData = this.dataMap.get(channel);
        Iterator<byte[]> items = pendingData.iterator();
        while (items.hasNext()) {
            byte[] item = items.next();
            items.remove();
            channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(item));
        }
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
    private void doEcho(SelectionKey key, byte[] data) {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        List<byte[]> pendingData = this.dataMap.get(channel);
        pendingData.add(data);
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    }
    private static void log(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new EchoServer(null, 8989);
    }
}
```

The program works with incoming connections. But when I make an outgoing connection, the program does not work. I need to make some connections in a row through the connect (String hostname, int port) and receive data in a method read(). The program stops working on the line clientChannel.register(...)

Comment: Unless you have over 1000 connections I suggest you use blocking NIO or Old IO. Its much simpler and the performance can be the same or better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for a [connectable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#isConnectable%28%29) key, e.g.

```
if (key.isConnectable()) {
  this.doConnect(key);
}
...
private void doConnect(SelectionKey key) {
  SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
  if (channel.finishConnect()) {
    /* success */
  } else {
    /* failure */
  }
}
```

Use [SocketChannel.finishConnect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#finishConnect%28%29) to determine whether the connection was established successfully.

Comment: I do not understand, please explain more. I'm calling from the main class Ehoserver.connect(hostname, port) where do I add these lines?

Comment: Your client should have an event loop which polls a selector for readiness events (just as you do for your server, @ startServer). Here you should have a check for connectable keys, such as the one I posted, just as your server logic does for acceptable, readable, and writable keys.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not give a positive result. I updated the code in the first message.

Comment: Yes, and I did not get the desired result

Comment: I advise you double-check for errors on your part, as the tutorial is a well-known resource for teaching how to use NIO.

Comment: socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("94.45.168.0", 22441)); Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException Why can it happen?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://goo.gl/C82ta).

An attempt will be made to resolve the hostname into an InetAddress. If that attempt fails, the address will be flagged as unresolved.

The resolution step evidently failed, meaning you attempted to connect to an unresolved endpoint address.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14709/discussion-between-super-and-user1221483)

Comment: Looks like I have almost everything figured out. http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/src/NioClient.java Tell me please, for each connection in the public static void main (String [] args) I have to create a separate NioClient and Thread? Is this normal if it is ~ 500 connections?

Comment: For every client you create to connect to your server, you require an NioClient, but you could modify it to avoid as many threads by sharing selectors.

Comment: how can I do this? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

This is my NIO Client example Ive been using. It gives a timed out open/write/read functions and is suitable for request-response messaging.

Tricky part is always how do parties recognize a packet is fully received. This example assumes

- Server gets one_line_command+newline (client->server packet)
- Client receives 1..n lines with ">>" terminator line without trailing newline in a terminator line (server->client packet)
- you could specify terminator to be ">>\n" but readUntil needs small fix in a newline parser

You could write 4-byte length header, fixed size packet splitter or delimiter 0x27 byte but make sure it cannot be a value of data payload. NIO read() or write() never assumes you receive a full packet in one call. Or may read two or more packet bytes in one read() buffer. It is up to us make a packet parser not loosing bytes.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class DPSocket {
    private boolean debug;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String charset;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream inBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer buf;
    private Selector selector;
    private SocketChannel channel;

    public DPSocket(String host, int port, String charset) {
        this.charset = charset==null || charset.equals("") ? "UTF-8" : charset;
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public boolean isDebug() { return debug; }
    public void setDebug(boolean b) { debug=b; }

    public void open(long timeout) throws IOException {
        selector = Selector.open();
        channel = SocketChannel.open();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
        channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        inBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1*1024);
        long sleep = Math.min(timeout, 1000);
        while(timeout > 0) {
            if (selector.select(sleep) < 1) {
                timeout-=sleep;
                continue;
            }
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid() || !key.isConnectable()) continue;
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                if (channel.isConnectionPending()) {
                    channel.finishConnect();
                    channel.configureBlocking(false);
                    if (debug) System.out.println("finishConnect");
                    return; // we are ready to receive bytes
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IOException("Connection timed out");
    }

    public void close() {
        try { if(channel!=null) channel.close(); } catch(Exception ex) { }
        try { if(selector!=null) selector.close(); } catch(Exception ex) { }
        inBuffer=null;
        buf=null;
    }   

    public void write(String data, long timeout) throws IOException {
        write(data.getBytes(charset), timeout);
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes, long timeout) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        long sleep = Math.min(timeout, 1000);
        while(timeout > 0) {
            if (selector.select(sleep) < 1) {
                timeout-=sleep;
                continue;
            }
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid() || !key.isWritable()) continue;
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                if (debug) System.out.println("write remaining="+outBuffer.remaining());
                channel.write(outBuffer);
                if (debug) System.out.println("write remaining="+outBuffer.remaining());
                if (outBuffer.remaining()<1)
                    return;
            }
        }
        throw new IOException("Write timed out");
    }

    public List<String> readUntil(String terminator, long timeout, boolean trimLines) throws IOException {
        return readUntil(new String[]{terminator}, timeout, trimLines);
    }

    public List<String> readUntil(String[] terminators, long timeout, boolean trimLines) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(12);
        inBuffer.reset();

        // End of packet terminator strings, line startsWith "aabbcc" string.
        byte[][] arrTerminators = new byte[terminators.length][];
        int[] idxTerminators = new int[terminators.length];
        for(int idx=0; idx < terminators.length; idx++) {
            arrTerminators[idx] = terminators[idx].getBytes(charset);
            idxTerminators[idx] = 0;
        }
        int idxLineByte=-1;

        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        long sleep = Math.min(timeout, 1000);
        while(timeout>0) {
            if (selector.select(sleep) < 1) {
                timeout-=sleep;
                continue;
            }
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid() || !key.isReadable()) continue;
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                buf.clear();
                int len = channel.read(buf);
                if (len == -1) throw new IOException("Socket disconnected");
                buf.flip();
                for(int idx=0; idx<len; idx++) {
                    byte cb = buf.get(idx);
                    if (cb!='\n') {
                        idxLineByte++;
                        inBuffer.write(cb);
                        for(int idxter=0; idxter < arrTerminators.length; idxter++) {
                            byte[] arrTerminator = arrTerminators[idxter];
                            if (idxLineByte==idxTerminators[idxter]
                                    && arrTerminator[ idxTerminators[idxter] ]==cb) {
                                idxTerminators[idxter]++;
                                if (idxTerminators[idxter]==arrTerminator.length)
                                    return lines;
                            } else idxTerminators[idxter]=0;
                        }
                    } else  {
                        String line = inBuffer.toString(charset);
                        lines.add(trimLines ? line.trim() : line);
                        inBuffer.reset();
                        idxLineByte=-1;
                        for(int idxter=0; idxter<arrTerminators.length; idxter++)
                            idxTerminators[idxter]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IOException("Read timed out");
    }

    // **************************
    // *** test socket client ***
    // **************************

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String NEWLINE = "\n";
        int TIMEOUT=5000;

        DPSocket dps = new DPSocket("myserver.com", 1234, "UTF-8");
        dps.setDebug(true);

        try {
            List<String> lines;
            dps.open(15000);

            dps.write("Command1 arg1 arg2"+NEWLINE, TIMEOUT);
            lines = dps.readUntil(">>", TIMEOUT, true);

            dps.write("Command2 arg1 arg2"+NEWLINE, TIMEOUT);
            lines = dps.readUntil(">>", TIMEOUT, true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = ex.getMessage();
            if (msg==null) msg = ex.getClass().getName();
            if (msg.contains("timed out") || msg.contains("Invalid command ")) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            } else {
                System.out.print("ERROR: ");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            dps.close();
        }
    }

}
```