# Non blocking client using NIO

Tags: java, client, nio, nonblocking

I'm new in NIO and i need to create simple non-blocking client with next api:

```
void start();
void send(String msg);
void stop();
```

Start method should create connection for specified host and port.
stop method should stop the client and release connection.
send should send messages to server.

So I have read documentations and I created simple client:

```
public class NonBlockingNIOClient {

    private DatagramChannel channel;

    public final static int MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 65507;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NonBlockingNIOStatsDClient.class);

    public NonBlockingNIOStatsDClient(String host, int port) {
      this.host = host;
      this.port = port;
    }


    public void start() {
        try {
            channel = DatagramChannel.open();
            channel.configureBlocking(false);
            channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(getHost(), getPort()));
            while (!channel.isConnected()) {
                LOGGER.debug("still connecting");
            }

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(channel.isConnected()) {
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();

        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new ClientException("Failed to start client", e);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            channel.disconnect();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new StatsDClientException("Failed to stop client", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void send(String msg) {
        LOGGER.debug("send: {}", msg);
        Validate.notBlank(msg, "message to sand cannot be blank");

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
        buf.clear();
        buf.put(msg.getBytes());
        buf.flip();

        try {
            channel.write(buf);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            getErrorHandler().handle(e);
        }
    }
}
```

How I understand from docs that `channel.configureBlocking(false);` does not guarantee that write method from channel will work in non-blocking mode. I guess I need to use selectors to achieve non-blocking behavior. But when I was trying to do next:

```
            Selector selector = null;
            try {
                selector = Selector.open();
                channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                while(channel.isConnected()){
                    selector.select();
                    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        SelectionKey key = iterator.next();


                        if(key.isWritable())
                        {
                            //do send
                        }
                        iterator.remove(); 
                    }
                }
                selector.close();
            }
```

In this case client does not respond to `send()` method because client was blocked by `while(channel.isConnected())`. Do you have any suggestions how I can make start method available and at the same time use selectors.

Comment: What exactly was the purpose of the apparently pointless spin loop on 'while (channel.isConnected())' in the first places? Just remove it.

Comment: Ok. So, I think I need to use queue into which the send() method will put messages to send and some logic in "if(key.isWritable()){}" block will take message form queue and send it to server. It's ok, this approach makes sense ?

Comment: I would rather ask you why you think you need to use NIO in a client at all. Unless you're dealing with multiple servers, there is really no point.

Comment: I just want to understand how I can implement such client. No I don't know how many servers will be used and also I don't know which technology (I/O or NIO) was used to implement server. I just want to know how it can be implemented in general and in which way and nothing more at current moment.

Comment: I strongly suggest you get it working with `java.net` first and then see whether you have any need to do any more with it.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27130710/185565 about request-response NIO client example. It provides a non-blocking single threaded client which is easiest to understand.