# java nio socketChannel.write() missing bytes

Tags: nio, socketchannel, filechannel

```
System.out.println(" @ bBuffer = " + bBuffer.capacity());

headerBuffer.rewind();
socketChannel.write(headerBuffer);

int writen = socketChannel.write(bBuffer);
System.out.println(" @ writen = " + writen);
```

`bBuffer` is an object of type `ByteBuffer` and it came from `FileChannel.map()` (it's an image file).  When I receive this image file on client, it wasn't a complete image--about half of image was missing.  So I checked how much bytes was written by printing some statistics to the console.  The output was:

```
 @ bBuffer = 319932
 @ writen = 131071
```

What happened to the rest of the bytes?   It seems that (319923 - 131071) bytes are missing.

Sometimes `written` is equals to `bBuffer.capacity()` and it's seems irrespective to file size or buffer capacity.

Comment: Try bBuffer.remaining() call, ByteBuffers are not supposed read or write everything instantly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27130710/185565

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes an invalid assumption. `read()` and `write()` aren't obliged to transfer more than one byte per call. You have to loop. But you're doing this wrong anyway. It should be:

```
while (headerBuffer.position() > 0)
{
    headerBuffer.flip();
    socketChannel.write(headerBuffer);
    headerBuffer.compact();
}
```

or

```
headerBuffer.flip();
while (headerBuffer.hasRemaining())
{
    socketChannel.write(headerBuffer);
}
headerBuffer.compact();
```

If the `SocketChannel` is in non-blocking mode, it gets considerably more complex, but you haven't mentioned that in your question.

You also need to check your receiving code for the same assumption.