# Java Socket Server MultiUser Issue ; How can I handle multiple sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I handle multiple clients from my java socket server using threads, and a list. Suppose that the socket server is a chat server.

```
//ServerSocket
ServerSocket servSock = new ServerSocket(port_num);
while(true){
    Socket sock = servSock.accept();
    userList.add(sock);    //List<Socket> userList.
    Thread t = new Thread(new SocketListener(sock, userList));
    t.Start();
}

//Socket Listener Class
public void run(){
     ...

     //sending part for broadcasting message 
     for(Socket sock : userList){
           if(sock!=userSock){
                     sock.write();.....
           }
     }
    ...
}
...
```

This kind of approach seems to have no problem if I have few clients connected. The problem of this is that...
(1) I have to approach to the 'userList' everytime I send something to another client. Of course I use the synchronized keyword on the list to sync the list, but I feel that it is still an overhead.

(2) If a socket is disconnected or became null, it will cause an error, or crash. It can be handled by a try-catch phrase inside the sending loop, but I don't think this is a smart approach.

My question is, will there be a better approach or pattern to deal with this kind of coding?

Comment: If you're looking for a best practice and your code is working as is, maybe you should consider posting a question at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Gemtastic There are a lot of `...`s in this code. It reeks a little of hypothetical code, which is off-topic on Codereivew.

Comment: Note: a socket didn't became null if you don't explicitly put null on the reference.

Comment: @EthanBierlein that's why I said "if your code is working as is" which I concluded from the fact that he seems to have working code since he's run something.

Comment: It works fine. It's a very abstract code, but I think this is enough on understanding the issue. The core issue is about the list of socket(the userList) that I use on approaching to other sockets.

Comment: I have given up on traditional socketIO and went full nonblocking nio approach, been very happy as I can easily do a simple single thread app or multiple  workers with clean interfaces. See this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/27130710/185565

Comment: "It can be handled by a try-catch phrase inside the sending loop, but I don't think this is a smart approach." That's too bad, because it is the only approach available. NIO doesn't change this. Nothing can. It is how TCP/IP is. Don't let your theories about 'smart' programming interfere with what is actually required by the problem domain.