# Java socket write immediately after read

Tags: java, sockets

Basically, what I want to achieve is to complete a ping-pang communication between a client socket and server socket.

The scenario should be like this:

1. Client establishes the connection to server.
2. Client sends "Hello" to server (via OutputStream), then start to read from server (via InputStream)
3. Server reads "Hello" message and print to console, then sends "Hello" to client (via OutputSteam).
4. Client prints the response message from server and exit.

**Server Socket**:

```
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080)) {
            while (true) {
                // Blocking here
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();

                String reqMessage = new String(inStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(reqMessage);

                String resMessage = "Hello";
                outStream.write(resMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                outStream.flush();
                System.out.println(String.format("Message '%s' has been sent to client", resMessage));

                outStream.close();
                socket.close();
            }
        }
```

**Client socket:**

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);

        OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write("Hello Server".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        outStream.flush();

        InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Received from server");
        System.out.println(new String(inStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        outStream.close();
        socket.close();
```

**My problem:**

Once the connection is established, both sides are blocked, no one is printing the proper message, just like they are waiting for each other. Once I shutdown the client, then the server prints all proper info. But if I removed the 'reading from server' part which is the InputStream part from client side, then both sides are working properly. I just got confused, why does it behave like this? if I want to make it work, what should I modify?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you studied NIO non-blocking socket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745686/java-nio-client/27130710#27130710

Comment: What comes to your problem have you tried calling `inStream.readAllBytes()` second time in a server to make sure an empty array is returned(=end of stream marker). If second call is never invoked before client closes a socket then EOF is not recognized in a network socket stream to be usefull for this function. You could define a message format `numOfBytes(64bit),databytes` and read accordingly in your server and client. Do not wait for a real end-of-file/end-of-stream state.

Comment: @Whome Yes, but I'm just warming up and practise some basic concepts, I think Kayaman gave the correct answer, all problems come from `readAllBytes()`, it keeps waiting until stream is closed which will never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `readAllBytes()`. It doesn't mean it reads all bytes that are available, it reads all bytes until the stream is **closed**.

```
String reqMessage = new String(inStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

will block until you close the client, because the server is still waiting for "all" the bytes. At the same time the client is waiting for the server to send something, which it of course can't do as it's still waiting for more data from the client.

You shouldn't be using bytes anyway, since you're writing text messages. Use `BufferedReader` with `InputStreamReader` and for example `PrintWriter` with `OutputStreamWriter` to write text. Don't forget that `readLine()` needs a newline from the sender, and specify the character encoding in `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`.