# Are Java Sockets FIFO?

Tags: java, sockets

Are different messages sent on the same socket always received in FIFO order from the other end?

I can't find this information anywhere, I know that TCP reorders packets but does it count also for separate messages on the same connection?

If not, what is a Java class for network communication that preserves FIFO order among two peers?

**Edit:**

As a comment pointed out there are no messages in sockets. What I was referring to is the usage of:

```
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
writer.writeObject(obj1);
writer.writeObject(obj2);
```

Are those objects granted to be received in the same order?

Comment: A Socket delivers **bytes** to the receiver in the same order that the sender sent them.  The TCP protocol implementation guarantees that data is not reordered.   The fact that the actual network packets may be dropped, retransmitted and/or received out of sequence is *dealt with* by the protocol stacks.

Comment: There are no "messages" on a TCP socket. It's a byte stream.

Comment: Using TCP(byte stream) need to handle a concept of message by using a delimiter(what if msg data had a delimiter?) or length-prefix(maybe 4-bytes aka 32bit field). Apps decide when to splice bytes to a logical message object. See this simple NIO client example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27130710/185565

Yes bytes are received in the same order as it's an "infinite" flow of bytes.

Comment: Java sockets are just… sockets.  The Socket and SocketChannel classes just delegate to the underlying system’s implementation of sockets.  Which means the behavior is the same as any C program that uses sockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are different messages sent on the same socket always received in FIFO order from the other end?

Sockets are not message streams. The abstraction does not support that concept.  Likewise, TCP is a protocol for sending a sequence of bytes.

A Socket delivers a stream of bytes to the receiver in the same order that the sender sent them. The TCP protocol implementation guarantees<sup>1</sup> that data is not reordered. The fact that the actual network packets may be dropped, retransmitted and/or received out of sequence is dealt with by the protocol stacks.

(You can design and implement a message-based application protocol that uses TCP as its transport protocol.  For example, designate specific byte values to mean the start and end of a message.  The application-level messages won't be reordered by TCP since the byte stream that represents them is not reordered.)

<sup>1 - I should qualify that.  TCP / IPv4 uses a checksum (a 16 bit CRC) in each network packet to guard against transmission errors.  However it is theoretically possible for packet to be corrupted in such a way that two bytes are transposed and the CRC is still valid.   The "guarantee" ignores this.</sup>

---

> What I was referring to is the usage of:
>
> ```
> ObjectOutputStream writer = 
>         new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
> writer.writeObject(obj1);
> writer.writeObject(obj2);
> ```

We have already explained that sockets preserve the order of the bytes.  So if any reordering were to occur in the above code and the matching receiving code, it would be as result of something in the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` APIs.

I did not find anything in the javadocs or the Java Object Serialization Specification that *explicitly* states that objects are written and then read in the same order.  However, that is how the protocol and APIs are designed to work, and how the implementation actually behaves.

> Are those objects guaranteed to be received in the same order?

In practice<sup>2</sup>, yes.  And you can verify this by examining the source code of the respective classes in the OpenJDK codebase.  (Any version.)

<sup>2 - If this wasn't true in practice, then *any* application that involved serializing / deserializing a stream of objects *could* break.  There *would* be Java bug reports, complaints that serialization is broken, etcetera.  And that would also happen if "they" changed this behavior.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this completely answers my question, summarize everything that was pointed out in comments and corrects the imprecision of my question

Comment: The code sample only shows one object (graph) being sent, so in what sense could there ever be reordering?

Comment: That was addressed by an update to the question.  Two objects are now sent.